# Windows 7 is no longer available on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have both Windows 7 x64 and Ubuntu 16.04 x64 installed on my laptop. I figured out that the Windows 7 option no longer appears on dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Run this command : `sudo update-grub`